# Add Github Branch to VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have just hired a developer to help me with a project.  He created a brach of the project and added it to the github repository.  I want to now add that branch to vs code.  That is to say, I have the main branch synced with vs code, but not the new branch.  I am wondering how I can add that new branch to my project folder on vs code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
git checkout name_of_your_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch all remotes:

`git fetch --all`

Switch the branch:

`git checkout <branch>`